# Что такое матрица в программировании и зачем она нужна?

Tags: матрицы, терминология

Что такое матрица в программировании и зачем она нужна? (в математике я тоже не знаю зачем она)

А наткнулся я это слово когда читал о NumPy(модуль python)

Comment: Ну вроде то же самое и затем же, что и в математике

Comment: У термина может быть несколько разных значений, поэтому лучше приведите контекст в котором вам встретилась матрица.

Comment: @defaultlocale читал я в интернете что такое NumPy(модуль python)